# Why use a DRV2700 high-voltage piezo driver in this application?

Tags: boost, flyback, switching-regulator, piezo, step-up

The [DRV2700](https://www.ti.com/product/DRV2700) from Texas Instruments is an integrated circuit for driving piezoelectric/capacitive loads at relatively high voltages (max. +/-100 V) while the supply voltage can be as low as 3.3 V. This is achieved by an integrated boost converter.

This image shows a typical application from the datasheet:

[image: DRV2700]

I found an article "[An ultra-low noise, high-voltage piezo driver](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6534351/)" in which a circuit for driving piezoelectric elements at even higher voltages is proposed that is also based on the DRV2700.

[image: Circuit based on the DRV2700]

However, as far as I understand that circuit, only the boost converting ability of the DRV2700 is used here to build a flyback regulator that delivers the high voltage for the output stage. I am surprised that a special integrated circuit for driving piezoelectric loads is used for just such an application, but in the end, only the "standard voltage regulating feature" is used to generate a high DC voltage.

**My question now is:** Couldn't a "conventional" DC/DC step-up converter also be used for generating a high DC voltage in this case, provided that the several 100 V DC voltage are possible? What is the advantage of the DRV2700 in this case that I don't see?

Comment: read the article that you linked ... it mentions DC-DC switching converters, and why they are unsuitable

Comment: "Instrumentation electronics capable of supplying high voltages traditionally fall under one of two architectural umbrellas: DC-DC switching converters, and linear-type amplifiers. While DC-DC converters are efficient and can work at very high voltages, they suffer from switching noise and limited control bandwidths." ... "We present a circuit with a hybrid architecture. The high voltage is generated by a galvanically isolated DC-DC converter ..."

That doesn't explain why the DRV2700 was used.

Comment: possibly because the designer is familiar with it ... not all choices have a purely technical reason

Comment: Of course, the designer will have had his reasons. I just wonder if another regular boost converter could have been used.

Comment: if the resulting power supply has the desired characteristics  then yes, a "regular boost converter" can be used